# How could I clean the history in the remote repo on gitlab

Tags: git

My ex-colleague put a lots of binary files on a project repo.

So currently, the repo size is about 20GB. a scaring huge size.

Is there other way can reduce the repo size without creating an new one .

I can accept abandoning those binary files

Thanks

Comment: Not without rewriting the whole history which is effectively like creating a new repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite any commit that contains the offending binary files and then force update the remote repository with your rewritten history.

Anyone who has pulled the bad commits from the remote repository will need to be aware of the change so that they can update their local repos to be consistent with the new history.

---

The command to rewrite history is [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Note that the documentation has some warnings about using this command and you should take them seriously. Rewriting history should not be done lightly and you should verify that the result is correct before you force update the remote repository.

Also, you need to be sure when you do force update the remote repository that no one has pushed anything to it between the time you started rewriting history and the time you're ready to update the remote repository. Before you start you should probably tell everyone what you're doing and that they shouldn't push anything. Alternatively you can just take the remote repository down.

After your history rewrite is complete and the remote repository is updated, users who need to update to the new history can do so by `git stash`ing their work, fetching the new history, then rebase onto the new history any commits they hadn't yet pushed, and finally un-stashing their work.

---

You might find it useful to learn a bit more about how git works before trying to perform this operation. There's a [free book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) available that covers it pretty well.